# The grammatical explanation of "After 10 minutes of me nagging her"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions, expression-choice

Can you please explain to me the reason of using "me" instead of "I" for the following sentence:

> "after 10 minutes of **me** nagging her".

Comment: It's not used much these days but we used to be taught that the posessive should be used in cases like this. In other words that it should be "after 10 minutes of **my** nagging her"

Comment: Sorry but that belongs rather to English Language Learners than here in ELU

Answer (score 1):

That's just how the construction goes. There are a good handful of English constructions where the subordinate clause has its subject argument marked for "object" case (if present), and the main verb is in a non-finite form (either progressive form or base form, depending on the construction).

Other examples:

> Thomas helped [him bring in the groceries]. 
>   I wasn't against [her making the speech].
>   Have you ever thought about [us meeting more frequently].

Note that in all of these, as well as the OP's example, the subject is actually optional. Compare to main clauses in English where the subject is mandatory in declarative sentences.